# about $p$-adic units in $\mathbb{C}_{p}$

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

I want to understand the proof of Lemma 11 in this report:
https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/how-to-explicitly-solve-a-thue-mahler-equation

Lemma 11: If  $z \in \mathbb{C}_{p}$  is a $p$-adic unit, then a positive integer  $\phi$  can be explicitly found such that
$$\operatorname{ord}_{p}\left(z^{\phi}-1\right)>\frac{1}{p-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

There exists a unit $z’$ if a finite extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ such that $z-z’$ is divisible by $p^2$. Let $f$ be the degree of the residual field extension of $F/\mathbb{Q}_p$, then $z’^{p^f-1}-1$ has positive $p$-adic valuation, thus $z’^{p^2(p^f-1)}-1$ is divisible by $p^2$.

Hence $z^{p^2(p^f-1)}-1$ is divisible by $p^2$.

Comment: Why exists a unit $z^\prime $?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}_p$ is the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Do you use Fermat's little theorem during  your proof?

Comment: The “finite field” version of it, yes.